# Salesforce CLI Installation error - The Requested Operation requires elevation

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, cli

I downloaded salesforce CLI from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli)

However when i run the .exe file, I get the error

[image: Error]

I searched for solutions online, and tried all options as suggested but unable to get past this error. If someone has encountered this error can you please suggest how you resolved it.

Comment: Seems like you do not have admin permission on your windows machine. Could you right click and run the exe file as administrator?

Comment: I do have permissions. I tried right clicking and 'Run as Administrator' option.